# JAXB namespace prefixes missing for root element

Tags: xml, jaxb, jaxb2

The namespace is not getting prefixed to my XML. I am getting the XML below when I marshal. I need it to be `ns2:ircSelfCheckDownload`.

```
<ircSelfCheckDownload xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/external/schemas/irc/v2 irc.xsd" 
xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/external/schemas/irc/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <lastUpdatedTimestamp>2015-07-06T12:15:26.657-04:00</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
</ircSelfCheckDownload>
```

Can you please let me know what I am missing?

My Code:

```
  Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();

  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.pjm.com/external/schemas/irc/v2 irc.xsd");

  marshaller.marshal(obj, writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me .Create a package-info.java file and inside that put this annotation

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace="http://www.example.com/external/schemas/irc/v2",
        elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns = { 
            @XmlNs(
                prefix = "ns2", 
                namespaceURI="http://www.example.com/external/schemas/irc/v2")
        }
    )
//put you package name
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

Comment: I got this working for me with a package-info.java file, very similar to the one above. When using the provided file, every element except the root element are prefixed with the namespace. To also prefix the root element I needed to drop the namespace parameter from the @XmlSchema annotation.